# Can we have test repo directory and opentest server in different machines?

Tags: opentest

Is it possible to host test repo and Opentest Server in different machines? If yes then how do we configure testRepoDir in server.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTest server needs read-only access to the test repo directory. If the test repo directory is stored on a different machine, you could create a network share to provide the required access. However, the fact that you need to do this sounds like you might be doing something the wrong way. The test repo should be under source control and, if that's the case, it should be possible to clone and/or pull from it on-demand to the machine where the OpenTest server is running.